# Python snake game Movement directions are problematic

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import randint
```

The problem with the program is that the snake does not move

Placement on page coordinates

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.body_size = BODY_SIZE
        self.cordinates = []
        self.squares = []

    for i in range(0, BODY_SIZE):
        self.cordinates.append([0, 0])

    for x, y in self.cordinates:
        square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE , y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tags='snake')
        self.squares.append(square)
    pass
```

Place on page coordinates for snake food

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        x = randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH // SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH // SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
        self.cordinates = [x, y]
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE , y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOR, tags='food')

    pass    


#? ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

for get size screen:

```
def window_size():
    window_width = window.winfo_width()
    window_height = window.winfo_height()
    txt_win_print = (f'this is window_width = {window_width}\n this is window_height = {window_height}\n................')
    print(txt_win_print)


    screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
    txt_sc_print = (f'this is screen_width = {screen_width}\n this is screen_height = {screen_height}\n')
    print(txt_sc_print)

    x = int((screen_width /2) - (window_width /2))
    y = int((screen_height /2) - (window_height /2))
    window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}')

    pass
```

move snake and food on screen for randint  :

```
def next_turn(snake, food):
    x, y = snake.cordinates[0]

    if direction == 'Down':
        y -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == 'UP':
        y += SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == 'Left':
        x -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == 'Right':
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.cordinates.insert(0, [x, y])
    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y , x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE,fill=SNAKE_COLOR)
```

Add points by eating food

```
    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if x == food.cordinates[0] and y == food.cordinates[1]:
        global SCORE
        SCORE += 1
        label.config(text=f'Score: {SCORE}')
        canvas.delete('food')
        food = Food()

    else:
        del snake.cordinates[-1]
        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])
        del snake.squares[-1]

    if check_game_over():
        game_over()

    else:
        window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)

    pass
```

Movement directions are difficult

I think this part code is problem , but I can`t fix it

for move snake on screen :

```
def change_direction(new_dir):
    global direction

    if new_dir == 'Left':
        if direction != 'Right':
            direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'Right':
        if direction != 'Left':
            direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == ' Up':
        if direction != 'Down':
            direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'Down':
        if direction != 'Up':
            direction = new_dir
        pass





def restart_program(): 
    pass



def check_game_over():
    pass


def game_over():
    pass



color_list = ['White', 'Black']
back_ground = random.choice(color_list)

direction = 'Right'

GAME_WIDTH = 700
SPACE_SIZE = 30
GAME_HEIGHT = 700
SNAKE_SIDE = 25
BODY_SIZE = 2
SPEED = 200
SNAKE_COLOR = '#20B2AA'
FOOD_COLOR = '#FF8C00'
SCORE = 0



window = Tk()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title('Snake Game')


label = Label(window, text=f'Score:{SCORE}', font=('Mangal', 30))
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, bg=back_ground, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

restart = Button(window, text='Restart', fg='red', command=restart_program)
restart.pack()


#! ////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Movement directions are difficult

```
window.bind('<Left>', lambda event: change_direction('Left'))
window.bind('<Right>', lambda evebt: change_direction('Right'))
window.bind('<Up>', lambda event: change_direction('Up'))
window.bind('<Down>', lambda event: change_direction('Down'))


#! ////////////////////////////////////////////////


window.update()

snake = Snake()
food = Food()
window_size()
next_turn(snake, food)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If it is problem on moving the snake, it is better to remove the food related stuff.  Also code posted in different code blocks and it is hard to understand their relationship.  It is better to provide a [mre] in single code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space in your condition for the up direction:

```
def change_direction(new_dir):
    global direction

    if new_dir == 'Left':
        if direction != 'Right':
            direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'Right':
        if direction != 'Left':
            direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == ' Up':     # ----> 'Up'
        if direction != 'Down':
            direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'Down':
        if direction != 'Up':
            direction = new_dir
        pass
```

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import randint



class Snake:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.body_size = BODY_SIZE
        self.cordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for i in range(0, BODY_SIZE):
            self.cordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.cordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tags='snake')
            self.squares.append(square)
        pass


class Food:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        x = randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH // SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH // SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
        self.cordinates = [x, y]
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE , y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOR, tags='food')


def window_size():
    window_width = window.winfo_width()
    window_height = window.winfo_height()
    txt_win_print = (f'this is window_width = {window_width}\n this is window_height = {window_height}\n................')
    print(txt_win_print)


    screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
    txt_sc_print = (f'this is screen_width = {screen_width}\n this is screen_height = {screen_height}\n')
    print(txt_sc_print)

    x = int((screen_width /2) - (window_width /2))
    y = int((screen_height /2) - (window_height /2))
    window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}')


def next_turn(snake, food):

    x, y = snake.cordinates[0]

    if direction == 'Down':
        y += SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == 'Up':
        y -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == 'Left':
        x -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == 'Right':
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.cordinates.insert(0, [x, y])
    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y , x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR)

    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if x == food.cordinates[0] and y == food.cordinates[1]:
        global SCORE
        SCORE += 1
        label.config(text=f'Score: {SCORE}')
        canvas.delete('food')
        food = Food()

    else:
        del snake.cordinates[-1]
        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])
        del snake.squares[-1]

    if False:
        pass

    else:
        window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food,)

    pass

def change_direction(new_dir):
    global direction

    if new_dir == 'Left':
        direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'Right':
        direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'Up':
        direction = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'Down':
        direction = new_dir
        pass


def restart_program():
    pass



def check_game_over():
    pass


def game_over():
    pass



if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = Tk()
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.title('Snake Game')
    color_list = ['White', 'Black']
    back_ground = random.choice(color_list)
    direction = 'Right'
    GAME_WIDTH = 700
    SPACE_SIZE = 30
    GAME_HEIGHT = 700
    SNAKE_SIDE = 25
    BODY_SIZE = 2
    SPEED = 200
    SNAKE_COLOR = '#20B2AA'
    FOOD_COLOR = '#FF8C00'
    SCORE = 0



    label = Label(window, text=f'Score:{SCORE}', font=('Mangal', 30))
    label.pack()

    canvas = Canvas(window, bg=back_ground, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()


    # restart = Button(window, text='Restart', fg='red', command=lambda: restart_loop)
    # restart.pack()

    window.bind("<Left>", lambda event: change_direction('Left'))
    window.bind("<Right>", lambda event: change_direction('Right'))
    window.bind("<Up>", lambda event: change_direction('Up'))
    window.bind("<Down>", lambda event: change_direction('Down'))

    # ! ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    window.update()

    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()
    window_size()
    next_turn(snake=snake, food=food)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't work ....(up , and down)

Comment: The sign for the y component in the next_turn function are also reversed. I don't know how diffrent parts of your code are related to each other. you can try the code I've sent.